# Strange behavior of Switch Case statement in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I understand that Java `switch case` are designed this way but why is this behavior in Java

```
    int x = 1;

    switch(x){
    case 1: System.out.println(1);
    case 2: System.out.println(2);
    case 3: System.out.println(3);
    default: System.out.println("default");

    }

output : 1
         2   
         3
         default
```

My question is why case 2 and 3 are executed?   I know I omitted break statement
but `x` was never 2 or 3 but `case 2` and `case 3` still executes?

Comment: Without a `break;` or `return;` it runs all the code in order.  This is not strange but completely normal for a switch statement.

Comment: Guys,  I already mentioned I know I am not using break statements intentionally. Please don't suggest me to use break statements after each case statement. My intention was just to explore the reason for this behavior.

Comment: I am confused as to what the question is.  When you put one statement after another, you want to know why they were executed in the order they appear?  A case statement is just a label.  It doesn't "execute" anything.

Comment: @Raedwald  Yeah that question better explains my concern and have better answers.So 'Fall through"  have some benefits in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I omitted break statement but x was never 2 or 3 but case 2 and
>   case 3 still executes?

Straight from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) :

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in
>   switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case
>   label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of
>   subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Answer (score 4):

There is no break statement so all case are executed

Use break statements

```
switch(x){
    case 1: System.out.println(1);break;
    case 2: System.out.println(2);break;
    case 3: System.out.println(3);break;
    default: System.out.println("default");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add break statement for each case. As there is no break statement all cases are getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Break` statement.

```
switch(x){
case 1: System.out.println(1);
break;
case 2: System.out.println(2);
break;
case 3: System.out.println(3);
break;
default: System.out.println("default");
}
```

Check  the **[The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)**

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in
>   switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case
>   label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of
>   subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.